# ESP32 less memory size

Tags: arduino

When i compiled my program it shows following error.

> Sketch uses 1527594 bytes (116%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
>   Global variables use 58884 bytes (17%) of dynamic memory, leaving 268796 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
>   Sketch too big; see http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#size for tips on reducing it.
>   Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.

I don't know what to do and how to do. please some one help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: What have you tried from the page suggested in the error?

Comment: Your program is too large. It is as simple as that. Only you know what you are importing or doing in your program. If you have a lot of graphics or other data then do whatever you can to reduce the size of those objects.